# Python: Deleting files of a certain age

Tags: python

So at the moment I'm trying to delete files listed in the directory that are 1 minute old, I will change that value once I have the script working.
The code below returns the error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mtime'`

```
import time
import os 
#from path import path

seven_days_ago = time.time() - 60
folder = '/home/rv/Desktop/test'

for somefile in os.listdir(folder):
    if int(somefile.mtime) < seven_days_ago:
        somefile.remove()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import time
import os

one_minute_ago = time.time() - 60 
folder = '/home/rv/Desktop/test'
os.chdir(folder)
for somefile in os.listdir('.'):
    st=os.stat(somefile)
    mtime=st.st_mtime
    if mtime < one_minute_ago:
        print('remove %s'%somefile)
        # os.unlink(somefile) # uncomment only if you are sure
```

Comment: `os.path.getmtime(somefile)` is briefer and also works in lieu of `os.stat(somefile).st_mtime`.

Answer (score 8):

That's because `somefile` is a string, a relative filename. What you need to do is to construct the full path (i.e., absolute path) of the file, which you can do with the `os.path.join` function, and pass it to the `os.stat`, the return value will have an attribute `st_mtime` which will contain your desired value as an integer.